# Nested synchronized map

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I safely put elements in

`ConcurrentMap <String, Set<Integer>> cmap = new ConcurrentMap<String, Set<Integer>>();`

I operate on my concurrent map as follows:

- If a key does not exist: put an entry with some string and a brand new
  `Set<Integer>`
- If there exists: add a specific `Integer` to this key's
  `Set<Integer>` value.

Comment: edited Right side should have been ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: Check out the docs for computeIfAbsent https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: which version of java you are using?

Comment: I am using version 1.7

Comment: @user9497425 My added was submitted before your edit involving `ConcurrentHashMap`, and somehow this conflict was not properly dealt with by the system. Please re-edit your question, to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

ConcurrentMap has a method to initialize the map value if missing. I assume also the set inside should be thread safe:

```
Set<Integer> set = cmap.computeIfAbsent(key,(k)->  Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>()));

set.add(value);
```

Before lambda:

```
    Set<Integer> set = cmap.get(key);
    if (set == null) {
        set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
        Set<Integer> prev = cmap.putIfAbsent(key, set);
        if (prev != null) {
            set = prev;
        }
    }
    set.add(value);
```

Comment: putIfAbsent doesnt seem to seem to exist?

Comment: @user9497425 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)

Comment: upvote for the pre-lambda one. Much as I like lambdas I find explicit steps to be useful for code that must be thread-safe.

Comment: Why do you check if prev is null? If prev *is* null you'll still get an NPE at set.add.

Comment: putIfAbsent was added in 1.8 (they couldn't have added it before either, as they didn't have default methods on interfaces before 1.8), so the "before lambda" snippet is bogus.

Comment: @bowmore previous comments are providing links to for 1.7. in fact putIfAbsent was added in java 1.5 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was looking at the Map interface. `ConcurrentHashMap`has indeed had this method from 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

In concurrent environment you probably should use concurrent map and concurrent set. For example `ConcurrentHashMap`, and `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())`. The `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent()` method prevent race condition of `if(!containsKey) put` mechanic.

So the code will looks like

```
public void add(String s, Integer i) {
    cmap.putIfAbsent(s, Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>()));
    Set<Integer> set = cmap.get(s);
    set.add(i);
}
```